# Are mixins now officially called decoys (and when did that happen)?

Tags: ringsize, monero-terminology

I was reading something written by a community member SamsungGalaxyPlayer, where they mention casually that "decoys" are the new name for "mixins".
First time I've heard that.  Can someone confirm and tell me why or when it happened?

Full quote:

> Transactions with zero decoys (previously named "mixins") have no ring signature protection. This is self-evident.

from [getmonero.org](https://getmonero.org/pl//2018/03/29/response-to-an-empirical-analysis-of-traceability.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "official" anything. The term appeared about 1.5 yrs ago and it has since caught on. Many share the thought that "mixin" is misleading.

In the "official" software, mixin got replaced with ringsize (=mixin+1)

See also: [Mixin vs Ring Size](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/mixin-vs-ring-size)

Comment: Additionally, I don't think "mixins" where called mixins in the first place. I've always seen "mixin" used as a property of ring signatures, not a name for the fake outputs.

Comment: Thanks so much.  The terminology can get very confusing.